# Symfony 2.7, Doctrine cascade remove

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to use the doctrine `cascade={"remove"}` but it doesn't work.

The situation :
I have announces that contains many pictures (one picture can refer to only one announce). I want that when i delete the announce from the DB it's remove the pictures too.

Here is my code :

Entity announce :

```
/**
 * Announce
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Announce\AnnounceRepository")
 */
class Announce
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Announce\PictureAnnounce", inversedBy="coverAnnounce")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cover_picture_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $coverPicture; 

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Announce\PictureAnnounce", mappedBy="announce", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $pictureAnnounces; 
}
```

Entity pictureAnnounce :

```
/**
 * AppBundle\Entity\Announce\PictureAnnounce
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="picture_announce")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Announce\PictureAnnounceRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class PictureAnnounce
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Announce\Announce", mappedBy="coverPicture", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $coverAnnounce;

    /**
     * @var Announce $announce
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Announce\Announce", inversedBy="pictureAnnounces")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="announce_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    */
    private $announce;
```

The code for the delete (i set coverPicture to null so i don't have a foreign key error when removing)

```
$announce->setCoverPicture(null);
$em->flush();
$em->remove($announce);
$em->flush();
```

But i have an error on foreign key

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

PS : I can't found how to render correctly my code :s

PS : This workaround works, but isn't it the way the cascade work?

```
if(count($announce->getPictureAnnounces()) > 0) { 
   $pictureAnnounces = $announce->getPictureAnnounces();
   foreach ($pictureAnnounces as $pictureAnnounce) { 
     $em->remove($pictureAnnounce);
   }
   $em->flush(); 
} // Then remove the announce
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `orphanRemoval=true` in your announce entity also in your child entity add `, onDelete="CASCADE"` update schema of your db and then try to delete your parent entity

Comment: With the onDelete="CASCADE", it's work (don't need the orphan removal (i have found it but by the way i understand the documentation ti's not what i need here)). I'm i bit suprised that my code doesn't work for the delete. It's seems logique to me that with the onDelete it's work because we work directly on the DB. Any idea why with only with the ORM it's fails?